# How to add rows and columns dynamically to a Breeze DenseMatrix in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I am hard-coding a matrix with the values below:

```
val m = breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix((1, 4), (2, 5))
val v = breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix((7, 8), (3, 6))
```

I want to insert these values on the rows and columns by reading from lists.

Comment: do you know the  number of rows and columns ahead of time?

Comment: And... what's stopping you? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have gone many of the methods in the documentation which doesn't explain any of the methods properly. Haven't been able to use any method as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found out:

```scala
val x =  new DenseMatrix(2, 3, Array(11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23))
```

which gives the matrix with 2 rows and 3 columns by slicing off the numbers 2 and 3 specified from the array.

The result is:

```
11  13  22
12  21  23
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `rows:Seq[Seq[Double]]`, where each entry in the outer ~eq is a row:

```
DenseMatrix(rows:_*)
```

If you know the matrix dimensions ahead of time, and you have DenseVectors for each row/column)

```
val dm = DenseMatrix.zeros[Double](rows, cols)
dm(::, c) := myColDenseVector
dm(r, ::) := myRowDenseVector.t
```

Alternatively, if you have a bunch of DenseVectors, you can say: `DenseVector.horzcat(columns:_*)`