# Scala breeze.linalg Densematrix: unable to assign columns

Tags: scala, matrix, breeze

I cannot assign a column via A(::,1) = DenseVector to a DenseMatrix A. Here is what I get in the
repl:

```
scala> val A=DenseMatrix.vertcat(DenseVector(11,12).toDenseMatrix,DenseVector(21,22).toDenseMatrix)
A: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Int] =
11  12
21  22

scala> A(::,1) = DenseVector(13,23)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
found   : collection.immutable.::.type
required: Int
   A(::,1) = DenseVector(13,23)
     ^
```

Scala version is 2.12, breeze version: 1.0. This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760132/) where it is stated that this should work. The problem persists if A is declared as a `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close...

```
A(::,1) := DenseVector(13,23)
```

https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet